# Crash when running app

Tags: ios, iphone

I have used pod update **--verbose --no-repo-update** command for pod update.

After that I run my project.

But App is crash automatically and give the error:-

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/XCTest.framework/XCTest   Referenced
>   from:
>   /Users/pksingh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/77C016C0-4A89-44C2-8616-4F32D1C2159C/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/79C56C0B-5C7C-40BD-9DAF-6838DC86FDB2/ContribCity.app/ContribCity
>   Reason: image not found

Anybody can help me. Please..

My Podfile coding is:-

platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'ContribCity' do

pod ‘AFNetworking’ 
pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
pod 'IQDropDownTextField'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
pod 'HNKGooglePlacesAutocomplete’
pod 'Kiwi', '~> 2.3'
end

target 'ContribCityTests' do

end

Comment: Sometime clean the code and build it might works.

Comment: I have done, but error not solved.

Comment: share your pod file

Comment: target 'ContribCity' do

pod ‘AFNetworking’ 
pod 'IQKeyboardManager'
pod 'IQDropDownTextField'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
pod 'HNKGooglePlacesAutocomplete’
pod 'Kiwi', '~> 2.3'
end

target 'ContribCityTests' do

end

Comment: do not put here in comments, add it in your question. What is your XCode version ? have you added frameworks in Embedded binaries ?

Comment: i have used also pod install command but error not solved.